# How to access current discussion settings in gutenberg via JS?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

We're struggling with the issue that occasionally comments are disabled for a post though the editors *never manually change this option* in Gutenberg (comments are enabled in global settings).

As a workaround I'd like to show up an JS alert to the human editor when editing a post and comments are disabled in Gutenberg.

I successfully enqueued a script via

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-block-editor-js', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/my-block-editor-js.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-blocks' ));
```

But I have no idea how to read the current discussion settings of the post currently being edited.

The only way I found is via plain Javascript:

```
// file my-block-editor-js.js
function isCommentsEnabledInBlockEditor() {
    // Retrieve comments checkbox by it's label text (German)
    const xpath = "//label[text()='Kommentare erlauben']";
    const matchElem = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    if (matchElem) {
        const id = matchElem.getAttribute("for");
        if (id) {
            return document.getElementById(id).checked;
        }
    }
}

function registerPublishBtnHandler() {
    const publishBtnArray = document.getElementsByClassName("editor-post-publish-button__button");
    if (publishBtnArray && publishBtnArray.length > 0) {
        const publishBtn = publishBtnArray[0];
        if (publishBtn) {
            publishBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                if (!isCommentsEnabledInBlockEditor()) {
                    if (!confirm("Comments are disabled. Still publish?")) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    registerPublishBtnHandler();
});
```

Is there better way to retrieve the current comments enabled/disabled value by using the block-editor JS API?